# When I store a Date field in Oracle database it always shows 00:00:00 hour ¿Is it problem of SimpleDateFormat class?

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, simpledateformat

In my Java action file, I am obtaining the actual date to store it in an Oracle database. However, when I store the date in the database, it always appear like 30/05/2020, 00:00:00. I mean, it is not taking the current hour, always appearing 00:00:00.

This is the java code that obtains the date:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdffecha_modif = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    String fechaModif = sdffecha_modif.format(new Date());
```

Is it a common error? Does anybody know what is happening?

Comment: Post the code which you are using to store the date/time into the database.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Please also post the definition of the column or table you are trying to insert into.

Answer (score 1):

You have not posted enough details and code to diagnose your problem. I can only guess, and I can fix two major problems.

## `java.sql.Date` versus `java.util.Date`

My guess: You may be using the `java.sql.Date` class that pretends to represent a date-only value without a time-of-day and without a time zone.

In contrast, the `java.util.Date` class represents a moment in UTC, a date with time-of-day on offset of zero minutes-hours-seconds.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

Never use either  `Date` class, nor `SimpleDateFormat`. These terrible classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

## Smart objects, not dumb strings

Exchange smart objects with the database rather than dumb strings. As of JDBC 4.2 we can exchange *java.time* objects.

The [`DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i1847) type in Oracle database is akin to the SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`. Be aware this type cannot represent a moment, cannot be used for a point in the timeline. Lacking a time zone or offset means these values can represent any moment only a range of about 26-27 hours, the range of time zones around the globe.

## *java.time*

The equivalent type in Java is `LocalDateTime`.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.MAY , 23 ) ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 12 , 30 ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of( ld , lt ) ;
```

Write to database.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ldt ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;
```

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both legacy and modern) and in standard SQL]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).