# Get timezone-less DATE from DB via JDBC Oracle driver

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, time

```
java.sql.Date date = resultSet.getDate("DATE_COLUMN");
// let's say we are reading '16/05/1993 from DB
```

Whenever the above gets called, JDBC Oracle driver does some shenanigans on the background with [adjusting the timezone](https://rogersuen.github.io/2015/03/timezone-for-oracle-jdbc-driver.html). So in the end, the UNIX epoch long stored inside java.sql.Date might not correspond to 16/05/1993/00:00:00 UTC as I would expect it to.

The respective datatype is `DATE` in Oracle Database 21c.

Is there any way to receive the `DATE` from a table in Oracle database in its pure form - with no undesirable timezone adjustments?

Let's say the `DATE` in the database is '16/05/1993', but if some timezone adjustments happen, it can easily reach my app as '15/05/1993' in its end form.

**TL;DR:** I just want the Oracle DB DATE to reach my app either

1. simply as three numbers - day: 16, month: 5, year: 1993
2. or UNIX Epoch time that would always correspond to 16/05/1993/00:00:00 UTC

Comment: please show the sql and more code

Comment: What's the type of the DATE_COLUMN column?

Comment: Try `LocalDate date = resultSet.getObject("DATE_COLUMN", java.time.LocalDate);`

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62104802/266304) and similar answers; in short, use java.time classes, not java.sql.date etc.

Comment: What *precisely* is the data type of your column? Did you mean literally the [`DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-5405B652-C30E-4F4F-9D33-9A4CB2110F1B) type in Oracle Database 21c? Or did you mean one of the `TIMESTAMP…` types? Show the relevant excerpt of your `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: I never understood the good way to combine Oracle database and Java, not even Oracle Java. Seems they forgot they came from the same company. In any case a good JPA implementation like Hibernate is very likely to take care of your issues for you. Then just use `LocalDate` in the Java side as others have already mentioned.

Comment: I suppose the bad hack would be reading the date as a string from the database and parsing it into a `LocalDate` yourself. Nothing you want if there’s any way you can get your JDBC driver to do the work for you.

Comment: @tgdavies, Basil Bourque: Yes, the respective datatype is DATE in Oracle Database 21c.